# How to render string script tags as React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I render a string script tag (rather, a list of them) as React components?

I've got the following going:

```
const scripts = [
  '<script src="https://myscript.com/snippet.js" id="some-important-id"></script>',
  '<script src="https://myscript.com/snippet2.js" id="some-important-id-2"></script>'
]
return (
  <> 
    <Helmet>
      {scripts.map((script, index) =>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: script }}/>
      )}
    </Helmet>
    <RestOfApp/>
  </>
)
```

The actual script values are pulled from the back-end so I can't just place the scripts into the component *as* components.

I had previously had this set up by only rendering `<script/>` tags and adding the `src` attribute, however I now need the custom `id` tags as well.

I *could* store the `src` and `id` values in the DB as well, but am looking to avoid that as it complicates existing client setup.

Comment: I don't understand the problem - isn't `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` rendering the `<script>` tags including their IDs?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I believe because the `<div>` can't be rendered inside the `<Helmet>` component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.createElement`.

```
{scripts.map((script, index) => {
  const element = document.createElement('script')
  element.src = script
  // element.async = true

  return element
)}
```

Side note, I've previously tried to use dangerouslySetInnerHtml myself and I think react prevents from doing so as a security measure (or for some reason it's greyed out and not used).  Loading external HTML from another site will also disable any scripts.  But creating a new element works.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current implementation that works but feels hacky, as I don't want to *have* to specify which attributes get included:

```
{scripts.map((script, index) => {
  const firstChild = (new DOMParser().parseFromString(script, "text/xml")).firstChild
  return <script src={firstChild.getAttribute('src')} id={firstChild.getAttribute('id')} key={index}/>
})}
```